# Rating system Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, rating, review

IMPORTANT: I'm not asking for the source code to do this, I'm just looking for someone to tell me how to do it and then I'll try by myself to do this.

Hello, I'm a Laravel beginner so I'm sorry if this sound logic to you, here is my question: I need to display review on the profile of my community, I need :

1. Short text for the review
2. Rating system between 0 and 5 (star rating)
3. Date of the review (Month and year)
4. First name and last name of the reviewer
5. Count the number of review for a profile

I'm absolutely not looking for the source code to do this, I'm just looking for someone to tell me like 'you have to create a database, put this data in.. etc' etc because I have absolutely no idea where to start to do this.
Once this will be done, I need to display each review of the right profile and make an average of the rating which is from 0 to 5

Thank you and have a nice day/night ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you probably will be using a database for convienence. But other methods are available too. What I would do? This is just a single example. This could not suite your environment. This is very global too as your question is.

1. Create a table called Review
2. Make some columns: id | rating | text
3. Create some tables with relationships to the review table
4. Get some stars input fields in your form
5. Make some post / get requests